# finished writing a poker hand evaluator looking for a new project

Tags: c++, projects, poker

just finished writing a five card poker hand evaluator in C++. now im looking for a new project about the same level of difficulty. maybe a very simple DOS command parser?

Comment: Whats the qestion again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you might be interested in the type of problems [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) offers. In particular, it sounds like you have a solution for [Problem 54](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=54) already.

Answer (score 2):

Try a calculator, one that takes a full formula, evaluates it and gives the result.

(96+123)/3-56^2+45*2

Answer (score 1):

Are you done yet? Why not write a 7-card evaluator, first using your 5-card evaluator and then find a direct way that does not require the 21 checks per evaluation? The latter is a challenge in caching and memory management! There are many sources of inspiration to be found online -- check out [Coding-The-Wheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup) to get started, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your hand evaluator to have more inputs - like being able to dynamically calculate strength should it know another hands worth of cards. From there, extend further to calculate strength based on knowing N hands. With this, you're half way to a very nice poker-bot - capable of working with other instances of itself against other players.

:D

Answer (score 0):

Complete source code for Texas hold'em poker game evaluator can be found here:

http://www.advancedmcode.org/poker-predictor.html

It is built for matlab, the GUI id m-coded but the computational engine is c++.

It allows for odds and probability calculation. It can deal, on my 2.4Ghz laptop, with a 100000 10 players game computation in 0,3 seconds.

An accurate real time computer:-)